# global $wp_query; Returns Null

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

Firstly this question is different to [this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/69380/wp-query-returns-null-when-results-exist) as I'm talking about accessing $Wp_Query from outside of a loop.

`What I'm trying to do`

I'm currently just attempting to make an ajax request from a script to a php file called `database.php` which looks like so.

```
if (isset($_GET["increase"])) {
    global $wp_query;

    echo var_dump($wp_query);

}
```

As seen I'm just trying to get anything from the $wp_query this is the output from log.

```
 XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost/WCBD/wp-content/themes/Test%20Computing/database.php?increase=1".jquery.js?ver=1.11.1:4 m.ajaxTransport.sendjquery.js?ver=1.11.1:4 m.extend.ajaxjquery.js?ver=1.11.1:4 m.each.m.(anonymous function)myscripts.js?ver=1.2:15 foo.vote_up(index):313 onclick
myscripts.js?ver=1.2:11 
NULL
```

So it seems that it loaded correctly.

I feel like I'm missing an obvious step or something at being able to access the $wp_query.

Thank you.

Comment: Is there anything else in the database.php file? If you're not pulling in the wordpress core somehow then $wp_query would never be defined in it

Comment: No it's completely blank, this is a image of the file layout http://i.imgur.com/mFrsDpe.png - with some information redacted

Comment: Placing a php file inside the theme directory doesn't make it WordPress aware.  You must load the WordPress core inside that file, but you should instead check out the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) on how to do ajax in WordPress via `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`.

Comment: @birgire Okay I'm pretty stuck, I've looked through all these pages and still cannot find a way to include the wordpress core inside that custom file. Do you have any other links which may be usefull?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better to make any function within "**action**".
$wp_query will be initiated already, if you make:

```
add_action('init','your_func');

function my_func() {
    global $wp_query;
    var_dump($wp_query);
    // or  var_dump($GLOBALS['wp_query']);
}
```